# 'Cannot instantiate abstract class' although class shouldn't be abstract

Tags: c++, abstract-class

So I have two classes. One has only purely virtual functions. THe other implements those functions and is derived from the first class. 
I get that i cant instantiate the first class. But when I try to create an object of the second class it fails as well.

This is how my second class looks in general:

```
class SecondClass  : public FirstClass
{
public:
     SecondClass();
virtual ~SecondClass(void);

void Foo();
void Bar();

}
```

Implementation:

```
SecondClass::SecondClass()
{...}
SecondClass::~SecondClass(void)
{...}
void SecondClass::Foo()
{...}
void SecondClass::Bar()
{...}
```

This how I instantiate it and get the Error:

```
SecondClass mSecClass;
```

Where am I going wrong here?

FirstClass.h

```
class FirstClass
{
public:
  FirstClass(void);
  virtual ~FirstClass(void);

  virtual void Foo() = 0;
  virtual void Bar() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Show the interface of `FirstClass`! Without seen its declarations it is impossible to tell whether `SecondClass` is abstract or not.

Comment: FirstClass declaration, please :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I added it =)

Comment: Copy/paste, don't try to enter it by hand.  The `FirstClass` you post won't compile, because you've tried to name the destructor `~SecondClass`.

Comment: Tips: use override when you override virtual functions, and read the error message; all half-decent compilers tell you which functions are pure within that class you try to instantiate.

Comment: don't put `void` inside a parameter list

Comment: @TemplateRex: Why? While unnecessary, why/how would it be harmful?

Comment: What exactly makes `SecondClass` abstract? I get that `FirstClass` is, because it has purely virtual member functions. But `SecondClass` adds the implementation for those. So it shouldnt be abstract, right?

Comment: @tzippy absolutely. The only reason you have error 'cannot instantiate abstract class' is that your SecondClass does not override all pure virtual functions of FirstClass.

Comment: idk what is wrong but this works fine:
class FirstClass
{
public:
    FirstClass();
    virtual ~FirstClass();
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};
FirstClass::FirstClass() {}
FirstClass::~FirstClass() {}
class SecondClass : public FirstClass
{
public:
    SecondClass();
    virtual ~SecondClass();
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
};
SecondClass::SecondClass() {}
SecondClass::~SecondClass() {}
void SecondClass::Foo() {}
void SecondClass::Bar() {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `~FirstClass()` destructor and leave out its constructor

```
class FirstClass
{
public:
  virtual ~FirstClass(void) {} // or use C++11 = default syntax

  virtual void Foo() = 0;
  virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

class SecondClass  : public FirstClass
{
public:
     SecondClass();
virtual ~SecondClass(void);

void Foo();
void Bar();

};

SecondClass::SecondClass() {}
SecondClass::~SecondClass(void) {}
void SecondClass::Foo() {}
void SecondClass::Bar() {}

int main()
{
        SecondClass mSecClass;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a2b9f2b2ff504f6c58de2a69b8f1f8da-6b864d01527066fb211cc4a5466784d9).

Comment: add firstclass destructor is right, that suppose to fix link error if there is one. however, I'm not sure how does that link to object initialize error?

Answer (score -2):

Define every function you declare, except for pure virtuals(virtual void foo() = 0).
try the below code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class FirstClass
{
public:
    FirstClass()
    {
        //
    }
    virtual ~FirstClass();
    virtual void Foo();
    virtual void Bar();
};
    FirstClass::~FirstClass()
    {
        //
    }
    void FirstClass::Foo()
    {
        //
    }
    void FirstClass::Bar()
    {
        //
    }




class SecondClass  : public FirstClass
{
public:
     SecondClass();
virtual ~SecondClass(void);

void Foo();
void Bar();

};

SecondClass::SecondClass(){
//
}
SecondClass::~SecondClass(void)
{//
}
void SecondClass::Foo()
{//
}
void SecondClass::Bar()
{//
}

int main()
{
    SecondClass name;
    return 0;
}
```